# how to Dismiss Custom Dialog Fragment when Clicked outside

Tags: android, android-fragments

I'm new to android, I'm facing an issue! I created a custom Dialog fragment which displayed the image when I click on it. and the Dialog fragment appears with that image. when I click outside nothing happens. And when I click little more down it displays the below image. I have surfed and I tried any methods but couldn't get it right! I think the custom Dialog fragment is taking the whole view.I tried `dismiss(), setCanceledOnTouchOutside(true),`implemented `DialogInterface.OnCancelListener` but i'm not able to dismiss the dialog fragment. Kindly Help.
here is my code:

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view=inflater.inflate(R.layout.frag_layout, container, false);
    Bitmap bitImage=getArguments().getParcelable("BitImage");
    ImageView imageView=(ImageView)view.findViewById(R.id.fragid);
    imageView.setImageBitmap(bitImage);
    return view;
}

@Override
    public void onCancel(DialogInterface dialog) {
        dialog.dismiss();
    }
}
```

Comment: `setCancelable(true);` add in `onCreateView(....)`

Comment: In my code, using `android.support.v4.app.DialogFragment`
and `android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog`, that happens automatically....

Comment: M D, I've tried that but it is same once again I'll then.

Comment: Try to set the builder.setCancelable(true) for dialog builder.